# Custom Webpack -- Assign properties to data from Angular Service within Webpack/Write Files based on Angular Template within Webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, webpack

My situation is that I have multiple SVG templates that have data binding on my Angular project, and I want to somehow be able to determine if the data that is going to be bound to these areas is going to fit or not (not get cut off/cover something else basically),somehow mark the products(the data coming in from the angular service) to symbolizes which template it best fits into, or even write/modify the template on an individual product basis and save a copy for each product that I could have the component reference instead.
**I am partly able to do this with some basic jquery within the component checking the natural width and height of objects coming into the templates, but it REALLY slows down page load, so it's not viable**

I came to the conclusion that I should use a custom webpack to do this, possibly write a loader that analyzes the data coming in from the angular service and figure out which template that specific product fits best. The loader could do the calculations to figure out what fits where.
The reason I want to do this in the webpack is because I ultimately need to do the calculations anyway, and it would really bog down the load time to try and do this much logic dynamically on user load, not to mention it's just redundant in my situation to figure this out more than once, as the product info will not change until the website is updated with a new API call anyway.

I currently have a property hard coded that indicates which template to use(a number corresponding to a template), but doing it this way limits the scope of possible templates, and opens up many possible programmer goofs, as well as the fact that it doesn't cover smaller issues that ARE noticeable, and becoming a problem.

So, my question has three parts:

- Is it possible to call an Angular Service/API call in general within a loader.js/ts file?
- Can I manipulate the data coming in from an Angular Service/API call and have it preserve those changes (changing a flag property of each product coming in from the service)? The interface in angular that handles the data coming in has an extra property that I could assign potentially in the webpack to denote which template to use.
- Could I write html files to a folder on the local project/to a database using that data from a service and the base templates?

I apologize for the wordiness, but the situation has a lot of unique parts that I feel are necessary to include. I don't need code examples so much as I just need to know if Webpack/Loaders can/should even do this. I'm obviously open to any suggestions as well as to other ways to solve this problem.

Notes:

All the code I really have so far for the webpack would be configuring my angular.json to run off of a custom-webpack.config.js file I created, it doesn't currently do anything.

The service executes an http request and is subscribed to by angular components that consume it's data, but I could possibly write a js promise and recreate the interface for the scope of the webpack/loader, which is why I think it may be possible.